How to come up with a “gerrymandering” index / “roughness” index of some closed $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ of finite area
The answer to this question is not objective, but I believe this to be an interesting mathematical problem, which has different approaches one may take to arrive at an answer, and I’m interested to see what others may come up with.
Gerrymandering is the process of drawing boundaries of constituencies in such a manipulative way such that a certain political party or group is favoured disproportionately to their size.
Often a district can very obviously be seen to be gerrymandered if it appears to be an “ugly”, “rough”, “unnatural” shape - for example, very uneven borders and panhandles that stick out of it. The 12 Most Gerrymandered Districts In America - Ranker gives the following example of Maryland’s 3rd district:

In reality, things may be more complicated and a “nice” looking shaped district may actually be heavily gerrymandered if it happens to over/underrepresent a certain demographic. For our purposes we will ignore such complexity and focus solely on the shape of a district.
Formally, let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed set of finite area. I’m wondering if we can come up with some index
$$g: \{ \text{such subsets $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$} \} \to [0,1]$$
such that a “nicely shaped” $E$, such as a near-circle/square/etc. has $g(E) \approx 0$, and a “roughly shaped” $E$, such as the shape of Maryland’s district 3 above, has $g(E) \approx 1$.
Some properties $g$ should have are that it should be invariant under scaling/reflection/rotation/translation of the shape $E$, as such transformations make the shape no better or worse.

An example of an attempt
An attempt at a solution to this problem is to let $g(E)$ be one minus the probability that, picking two points $x_1, x_2 \in E$ uniformly at random, that the line connecting $x_1$ and $x_2$ lies entirely within $E$.
One positive of this index is that all convex $E$ have $g(E) = 0$, i.e. not at all gerrymandered - a value we may want since convex sets have smooth boundaries, and are path-connected. $g$ is also invariant under rotations/translations/etc.
A disadvantage of this index is a district may be considered heavily gerrymandered if there is a large hole, or several large holes within it, perhaps representing large lakes/seas in a real world setting. Also, “smooth” districts that are very much non-convex, such as a banana-shaped district, may be considered heavily gerrymandered.

What I’m looking for in an answer
I’m wondering if:

There are any standard indexes for this problem or similar problems that someone has previously come up with

Anyone has a particularly interesting idea for such an index.



NB. We may wish to extend this question to $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ rather than $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ in a natural way.

There are several notions of "compactness" of regions, but conventionally a score of $1$ means as compact as possible. See, e.g., https://fisherzachary.github.io/public/r-output.html

N.b. measures involving perimeter may suffer from issues measuring length a la the Coastline Paradox. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox

I’m voting to close this question because this is a hard problem that many mathematicians have worked on. MSE is not a suitable place to ask for what's in the literature. Look up gerrymandering mathematics in google scholar.

Also, sometimes the region being divided itself is rough, so unadjusted measures of roughness of subregions along a rough boundary of the region can be high, even if the discretionary part of the subdivision is as "nice" as possible. Pursuant to partitioning Maryland, for example, the eastern shore of Chesapeake Bay, currently part of MD-1, has a higher fractal dimension (~1.46) than even the famously rough coastline of Norway (~1.37).

In your example, any rectangle or ellipse is "not at all gerrymandered", even if one dimension is much larger than the other.

@EthanBolker It seems to me that "This is a well-studied field" with some links to relevant survey articles (pun serendipitous) would comprise a reasonable answer
